# How to change default root password for Live Kali Linux - USB persistence

Tags: password, root, kali-linux

After making a USB Live with Persistence stick, I tried to change root default password (using `passwd`) to no avail. Every time I reboot it resets to the default one. All other changes I've made (e.g. keyboard layout change, language change, update & upgrade all packages) do persist, except this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Kali's [forum](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?1890-Live-persistence-install-on-bootable-USB-not-saving-root-password-change), they suggest `sed`, I use a text editor as root but either will work. `sed` syntax is scary if you're not used to it.

You can just comment out the line that is setting the password to a default value on boot. The config file is:

```
/lib/live/config/0031-root-password
```

Once this has been commented out by adding the `#` in front of the `usermod` command then your password will no longer be changed back to the default value every time you boot up.